# Forecasting: Turn a basic formula to an ARIMA model

Tags: forecasting, arima

What ARIMA model best represents a formula like this one.

$$R_{T_i}=\frac{R_{T_{i-12}}+R_{T_{i-24}}}{2}\times{TREND}$$

I thought that an

```
arima(0,0,0)(1,1,0) or arima(0,0,0)(2,1,0)
```

Would do the trick. But it does not. Any suggestion?

Comment: what is $R_{T-12}$

Comment: @Hamed It would be. Calculating a Return for period T (which i dont know). Using the return from a year ago and 2 years ago + a trend

Comment: I removed the superfluous "sum" from your formula. I didn't fix some other things I think you probably intend differently (note how Hamed has written some $R$ terms slightly differently; I think that's probably what you mean), so you may find you wish to make additional changes to the LaTeX.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks. Do you have any idea with respect to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be backward shift operator and trend=$\mu_t$. Then,

$$
(\frac{2}{\mu_t}-L^{12})R_{T_i}\mu_{T_i}=({L^{24}-L^{12}}) R_{T_i}\mu_{T_i}
$$

that I do not think it is similar to an explicit ARIMA model.

Comment: thanks! If I don't know $R_{T_{i}}$ ?

Comment: as far as I realize, if you assume $R_{T_{i}}$ is unknown, then two side of your equation is unknown (trend parameters is unknown as well) and I have no ideas. sorry